# Android BottomNavigationView Truncating Text

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

Is there a way to disable BottomNavigationView's implementation of slighting enlarging the text/icon of a selected item?

Thanks,
Otterman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override some default values for **Text** :

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">24sp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">24sp</dimen>
```

For **icons** (32dp) :

```
    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) configurationActivity.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View iconView = menuView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.icon);
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = iconView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 32, displayMetrics);
        layoutParams.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 32, displayMetrics);
        iconView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```